# how do i place text over images on hover with transition without it initially loading?

Tags: css, hover, transition

I'm a VERY beginner with CSS and slowly teaching myself how to code to build an online portfolio.

I currently have thumbnails of images that are links, and I want to apply a transition using CSS over the images so that a color block with text fades in when hovered, and goes away when not.

I've found the perfect solution here (scroll until you see three thumbnails): http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/#

This method works fairly well. But the problem that irks me is that when I view the results on Chrome, I see the transition load as the page is loading...so fast almost like a flicker. And for some reason it's only on Chrome. I viewed it on Safari and it's fine.

You can view the problem here in chrome: **www.hellolinda.com** (sorry, I don't have enough reputations to turn that into a link...lol.)

I've found numerous articles on how to prevent the initial load from happening (like this: http://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/) but haven't had much success.

Any tips would be great!

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail-list">
<a href="../01/">
  <img src="images/infographic_sm.jpg" width="200" height="146">
  <span class="thumbnail-text"><span>AmLaw 200<br><div class="caption">Print, Infographic</div></span></span>
</a>
```

And the CSS

```
.thumbnail-list {
float: left;
margin: 0 25 25 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

span.thumbnail-text {
background: #f94639;
color: white;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 19px;
line-height: 1.15;
letter-spacing: .5px;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
height: 146px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 200px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms;
transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.thumbnail-text span {
display: table-cell;
text-align: left;
padding: 75px 0 0 15px;
}

.caption {
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: white;
padding: 8 0 0 0;
text-align: left;
position: left;
line-height: 15px;
}

.thumbnail-list a:hover span.thumbnail-text {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Also...it's not just happening the very first time the homepage loads, it happens whenever the user clicks back to the home page, too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the transiton effect from `span.thumbnail-text` and add it after the user hovers the thumbnail. Also change `<span class="thumbnail-text">` to `<div class="thumbnail-text">`, it's not good to have a DIV inside a SPAN.

```
.thumbnail-list {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail-text {
    background: #f94639;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    height: 146px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.thumbnail-text span {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 75px 0 0 15px;
}

.thumbnail-list a .thumbnail-text,
.thumbnail-list a:hover .thumbnail-text {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
   transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.thumbnail-list a:hover .thumbnail-text {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This works great. Also, thanks for the tip about the placement of div and span. =)

Comment: so, i just realized this now, but when the image is no longer hovered, the transition doesn't fade out, it just flips back to the image. any way to remedy that? thanks!

Comment: My answer is updated to include a fade out after the image is no longer hovered. @linda

Comment: thanks for the input. i tried it and it went back to causing the slight flicker during page load.

Comment: however..i did go back to using "preload" with jQuery...and it worked...but i also had to update some of the transition values. i think it might be a bug within chrome because it worked fine in safari. were you able to test your updated code somehow @chrisbedoya?

Comment: Yeah but using JSFiddle, might be something other code that's causing the bug. http://jsfiddle.net/D8tNg/